# Setting up Proxy for adding special anti-phishing detection headers

Tags: facebook, authentication, proxy, http-headers

We're running an event where visitors will register with Facebook onsite and will be given RFID tags for photos and wall posts during the event.

We're running into an issue where Facebook's anti-phishing measures are blocking our app because we have had so many Facebook auth requests originating from the same IP (we have a single broadband connection terminating at our event) in a short amount of time.

Facebook informed us we should proxy the requests so that we can add the following 2 headers before the request is finally sent over to Facebook.

X-Forwarded-For: (originating IP address of Client)
X-Forwarded-For-Sig: (Fields below delimited by “|” with HMAC-SHA1 hash.)

They explained how we should construct the values of the headers, but we're having trouble with getting a proxy set up. We've looked into nginx and squid (we have a local Linux server located at the event, but it is behind the router so it has a local IP).

Has anyone successfully set this up with Squid or other proxy software? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Chris

Comment: So no one has had this issue before?